# Trouble factoring an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

I've got the term $-1 + 2b^2 + 2b\sqrt {b^2-1}$ appearing several times within several larger expressions. It is easy to see that this expression factors into ${(b+\sqrt{b^2-1})^2}$, but when I use `FullSimplify` or `Factor` it doesn't change.  Is there a way to make *Mathematica* factor this expression automatically? $b$ is defined to be real and $>1$.

Answer (score 2):

The following, although rather unsatisfying, does produce the desired result.

```
term = -1 + 2 b^2 + 2 b Sqrt[b^2 - 1]
Factor[Simplify[term /. b -> Cosh[z], Sinh[z] > 0] // TrigExpand]
    /. Sinh[z] -> Sqrt[Cosh[z]^2 - 1] /. Cosh[z] -> b
(* (b + Sqrt[-1 + b^2])^2 *)
```

Indeed, the second expression, with a `LeafCount` of `13`, is simpler than the first, with a `LeafCount` of `19`.

Depending on the details of the actual problem you wish to solve, working with hyperbolic functions throughout instead of `b` might be preferable.